# Object is possible 'undefined' in constructor

Tags: typescript

New features in Typescript look strange for me. In such construction it shows a warning that the `_process` variable can be undefined, however next command is ok, check the picture

```
constructor(
  private _process: NodeJS.Process | child_process.ChildProcess
) {
  super();
  _process.send({});
  _process.on('message', (_msg: any) => {
    //
  });
  ...
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That wasn't about `_process` object that was about `send` method wich may be undefined in `NodeJS.Process`